Insuffient Memory in Sql Server but Small Query
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. (mscorlib)
I use SSMS. I meet this bug when i was working with ADO.NET, I'm click into Database and click on New Query, then it show me this error message. I'm researching and know that, this error just usually occur when execute a big sql file. But at here, I only want to open a select Top 1000 query or even a empty query and it occurs :((
I'm delete SSMS, delete SqlServer(in control panel + Program file + Program file X86 + Appdata + SQL2022). And clear the memory by: DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL') but it's still occur.
I'm so gratefull by everyone helps

Each tabs' results eats memory, also, in some versions it also leaks memory even if you close tabs, so the only thing to do is restart SSMS. Your steps wouldn't help, but perhaps you can upgrade to latest SSMS to see if problem goes away

The error is on the client not the server so DBCC won't help. How much RAM does your client machine have?

In  SSMS, select default database (not Master) before opening New Query.
